# CSS: change multiple tags on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to change multiple tags (body's background color, `.text` class's text color, and url link for `.url` to appear) in my html on mouse hover on one element in CSS.

The below code is not working (the url tag appears, but background color and `.text` color does not change).

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.text {
  color: blue;
}

.url {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 150px;
  top: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.img:hover > body {
  background-color: black;
}

.img:hover > .url {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.img:hover > .text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <h1 class="text"> Neon Cabbage </h1>
    <h2 class="text"> 2nd Website </h2>
    <div class="img">
      <a href="main.html"><img src="images/cabbage.jpg" id="cabbage" width="200" height="200" onmouseover="this.src='images/cabbage2.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='images/cabbage.jpg';"></a>
      <a href="main.html" class="url">click!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have a miss understanding of what CSS can achieve, what you are after requires the assistance of Javascript.

I see in your code that you have things like;

```
.img:hover > body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

The img tag is inside the body in the DOM, and Put simply CSS can only effect child elements inside one-another, therefor it is not possible for it to change the background of the body. for example given the following html structure...

```
<div class='parent'>
   Parent
   <div class='child'>Child</div>
</div>
```

`.parent:hover .child { color: red; }` will change the color of the child.

`.child { }` cannot do anything in CSS to effect the .parent class style. This is because of how the browser traverses the DOM and applies classes.